# Traduzir textos do inputs do WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Instalei o WooCommerce em meu tema, porém, quando clico em *Login*, *Sign up*, tudo isso está em inglês. Como traduzir esses pequenos textos? Só consegui traduzir a loja, o painel e algumas outras coisas.

Answer (score 3):

Conforme a documentação do plugin em [*Translating WooCommerce (Localization)*](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/woocommerce-localization/), estes são os passos:

1. definir a linguagem do site no `wp-config.php`

   ```
   define('WPLANG', 'pt_BR');
   ```
2. a seguinte notificação deveria aparecer no *dashboard*

   [image]
3. se não aparecer a notificação, é necessário forçar o download da tradução, indo à

   > WooCommerce > System Status > Tools > Force Translation Upgrade

Uma vez feito isso, o plugin é traduzido na administração e no tema (nas partes que são mostradas por ele):

[image]

Comment: Na verdade `WPLANG` foi depreciado na última versão do WordPress. O que precisa fazer mesmo é baixar os pacotes de tradução ou baixar o WordPress traduzido em http://br.wordpress.org/, depois de feito isso é possível alterar o idioma em "Configuraçoes > Geral" na opção "Idioma do site". Feito isso é só seguir do passo 2 em diante.

Comment: Obrigado, já foi !

Answer (score -2):

Não consegui **Forçar a atualização**, conforme citado em inúmeros posts na web. Minha versão de WooCommerce é a 2.5.2, com o WP 4.4.2.

A maneira que encontrei foi baixar os arquivos de tradução do WC manualmente, e colocá-los na pasta de tradução de *plugins*. Estando setado o WP como pt_BR, tudo correu como esperado.

Para baixar os arquivos de tradução (.PO e .MO) em português brasileiro, basta ir ahttps://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce-language-packs/blob/master/packages/pt_BR.zip

Depois, extraia o conteúdo em **wp-content/languages/plugins** e o WooCommerce fica traduzido.